# MDM that can control wifi and bluetooth

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

My boss just come up with an idea of having a mobile device management that can control the flow of data (access) from bluetooth and wifi to the iOS devices.

I've actually configured a Profile Manager (mdm) on Lion Server in the past so I'm a little bit familiar with mdm but not sure with the bluetooth access.

Where can I start?

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer on what you want to control on the iOS devices wrt bluethooth?  You want to restrict what a user can do with his bluetooth device?

Comment: @Tonin Hi, my boss is not around so Im not sure what does he want but I supposed he wants to know if its possible to restrict the usage of bluetooth in iOS devices via mdm...

Answer (score 3):

[BoxTone EMM](http://boxtone.com/iphone-management.aspx) does both.

> Configure device security with dozens of policy controls including encrypt device, disable iCloud, **disable camera/wifi/Bluetooth**, enforce strong passcodes, etc

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a MDM solution to set profiles that restrict bluetooth or Wi-Fi. The [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) can create these profiles and you can email them, post them through dropbox, upload them to a website, etc....

iOS will see those files and install them pretty much without hassle whether you use MDM to get them out or any other means that's convenient

The real art is in getting proficient on test devices how profiles work, when you want to prevent their removal and thinking through how you will set policy to not cause too much work but also lock things down in a reasonable manner.

Comment: Except for one thing... AC requires a Mac. Many IT departments don't have one in their LAN. Now, will a Mac server plus AC be cheaper than an MDM solution like SOTI, AirWatch, MobileIron, or BoxTone? Probably. But every IT shop I've worked in had little to no OS X expertise other than me, and it's just much easier to get a Windows Server based solution implemented. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @Dave You're not alone - getting that first Mac is a large step for lots of IT orgs. +1 on your solution for people that prefer that OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of Mobile Device management (MDM) vendors providing the ability to control WiFi and Bluetooth network. Check out [MDM Community](http://www.mobiledevicemanagement.io/mobile-device-management-comparison/) to know which MDMs support WiFi configuration. I am too lazy to list it out here.

Almost all MDM vendors support Bluetooth policy. I am listing some of the MDMs which have Bluetooth configuration, since the comparison is nowhere to be seen. I did a small research on this but there was a little availability of data and that was boring. So, I'm not listing all of them, and the list is in alphabetic order.

1. Hexnode
2. JAMF
3. MaaS360
4. MobileIron
5. SOTI